# Firefox: getting back to older version

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, updates

Firefox is releasing new version every alternate month.

```
v4.0 on March 22nd, 2011 
v5.0 on June 21st, 2011
v6.0 on August 16th, 2011
```

It can be because of the competition with google chrome.

But most of the addons are still aren't supporting newer versions. I realized this today when most of my addons stopped working when my Firefox was updated to 6.0.1

We do have option to increment the version but is there option to get back to previous version. Actullay  this questions sounds like "***i have windows seven and i want to go back to Win XP*** " :-P

Downloading previous version and installing it is the only option i see right now.
but i dont want to lose Bookmarks,history etc.

Any comment is appreciated.

Comment: What addons that you use don't support new version of firefox? (I'm just curious)

Comment: @Beniamin: That's secret... :P

Comment: Be careful using old versions. They have already stopped releasing security updates for version 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [MozBackup](http://mozbackup.jasnapaka.com/) to save all your preferences, bookmarks and addons with associated settings.

You can use [oldversion.com](http://oldversion.com/) to get the version you want.

I personally can wait for the addons to update. It usually is just a number change in the addons themselves.

Edit:
You can also [change](http://www.bluishcoder.co.nz/articles/mozilla/disable-extension-check.html) a setting in about:config to force the addons to work. I haven't tried this my self. Also I remember there was a way to enter the addons themselves and manually change them to 6.0.1 (or what version you have).

Comment: Compatibility Reporter lets you use addons that "dont't support" current version of firefox. You can find it here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/add-on-compatibility-reporter/.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in most cases your Firefox [profile](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Managing-profiles) is compatible with multiple versions. I have always gone back and forth between beta and stable releases using the same profile and this only failed to work once (which was easily resolved by deleting a file). In fact you can use one profile with multiple versions of Firefox across different computers and OSes.

All versions of Firefox can be found at
http://releases.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/

Answer (score 0):

You can also download Firefox 3.6 [on the official website](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all-older.html) and then only apply the upgrades (4, 5, ...) that you want.